# Is it possible in a Sybase SQL query to substitute a string variable for the where clause?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

I have two stored procedures that have different input signatures, but are otherwise identical and would like to consolidate them.  I tried to simulate "overloading" the signature and then just testing which input variable is null to appropriately set the final where clause.  I haven't figured out how to de-reference the string literal.

Procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_providers (@p_id bigint)
SELECT
   ...
WHERE p.p_id = @p_id

CREATE PROCEDURE get_providers (@ssn varchar(9))
SELECT
   ...
WHERE p.ssn = @ssn
```

Trying to add this logic to set a dynamic WHERE clause:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_providers (@ssn varchar(9), @p_id bigint)

DECLARE @clause varchar(100);
SELECT clause = 'p.p_id = @provider_id';    

IF @ssn is null
select clause = 'p.ssn = @ssn';

SELECT
   ...
WHERE @clause
```

Output:

```
ERROR: SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near '(end of line)' 
on line 50 Error Code: 102
```

(note: line 50 is "WHERE @clause")

Comment: Why not just have an if statement with two selects?

Comment: the select statements are very long...trying to reduce procedure code

Comment: for performance reasons they are still better off as two statements, especially if it is in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a complete query string and execute it  Here is an example

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql = '
select . . .
from . ..
@whereclause';

select @sql = replace(@sql, '@whereclause', coalesce('where ' + @clause, ''));

exec(@sql);
```

You can't have just one part of the query be a string.

Comment: thanks, I tried that and am having issues with the syntax...

I run "select @@version" which returns 16.0.0.1915, but:

declare @c varchar(25)
select @c = "select @@version"
exec @c

returns: ERROR: SQL Anywhere Error -143: Column 'select @@version' not 
found Error Code: 207

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up Watcom SQL and T-SQL. Both are supported by SA but you cannot mix them.
The following both work:

```
-- Watcom
begin
declare @c varchar(25);
set @c = "select @@version";
execute immediate @c;
end;


-- T-SQL
declare @c varchar(25)
set @c = "select @@version"
execute(@c)
```